# No module named 'tensorflow_fedarated'

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, federated-learning

I'm on windows but even in google Collab I cant import it.
and I do have proper internet.

```py
from tensorflow_federated import python as tff
```

Comment: What about `!pip install`ing it?

Answer (score 3):

You can install the released TensorFlow Federated Python package using as shown below

```
!pip install --upgrade tensorflow-federated
```

Then you can import required modules as shown below

```
from tensorflow_federated import python as tff
```

*Note: Currently you can install only on Ubuntu and macOS.*

For more details you can refer you can refer [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/install)

Comment: note that there may be other issues using colab; in particular, see the `nest_asyncio` usage in TFF's [tutorials](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification#before_we_start)